# A function made in my contract while trying to compile the contract showed this; TypeError: Referenced declaration is neither modifier nor base class

Tags: error, modifiers, declaration

```js
//SPDX-Licence-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract PurchaseAgreement {
    // VARIABLES
    uint public value;
    address payable public seller;
    address payable public buyer;

    enum State { Created, Locked, Release, Inactive}
    State public state;

    constructor() payable {
        seller = payable(msg.sender);
        value = msg.value / 2;
        // buyer = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    /// The function can not be called at the current state
    error InvalidState();

    /// Only buyer can call this function
    error onlyBuyer();

    /// Only buyer can call this function
    error onlySeller();

    modifier inState(State state_) {
        if (state != state_) {
            revert InvalidState();
        }
       _;
    }

    

    modifier onlyBuyer() {
        if (msg.sender != buyer) {
            revert onlyBuyer();
        }
        _;
        
    }

    modifier onlySeller() {
        if (msg.sender != seller) {
            revert onlySeller();
        }
        _;
        
    }

    

    function confirmPurchase() external inState(State.Created) payable {
        require(msg.value == (2 * value), "please send the 2x the purchase amount" );
        buyer = payable(msg.sender);
        state = State.Locked;
    }

    function confirmReceived() external onlyBuyer inState(State.Locked) {
        state = State.Release;
        buyer.transfer(value);
    }

    function paySeller() external onlySeller inState(State.Release) {
        state = State.Inactive;
        seller.transfer( 3 * value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a naming collision between the modifiers and the custom errors of `onlyBuyer` and `onlySeller`.

I would recommend to rename the errors to `OnlyBuyer` and `OnlySeller`.

Full code would be:

```js
//SPDX-Licence-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract PurchaseAgreement {
    // VARIABLES
    uint public value;
    address payable public seller;
    address payable public buyer;

    enum State { Created, Locked, Release, Inactive}
    State public state;

    constructor() payable {
        seller = payable(msg.sender);
        value = msg.value / 2;
        // buyer = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    /// The function can not be called at the current state
    error InvalidState();

    /// Only buyer can call this function
    error OnlyBuyer();

    /// Only buyer can call this function
    error OnlySeller();

    modifier inState(State state_) {
        if (state != state_) {
            revert InvalidState();
        }
       _;
    }
    
    modifier onlyBuyer() {
        if (msg.sender != buyer) {
            revert OnlyBuyer();
        }
        _; 
    }

    modifier onlySeller() {
        if (msg.sender != seller) {
            revert OnlySeller();
        }
        _;
    }

    function confirmPurchase() external inState(State.Created) payable {
        require(msg.value == (2 * value), "please send the 2x the purchase amount" );
        buyer = payable(msg.sender);
        state = State.Locked;
    }

    function confirmReceived() external onlyBuyer inState(State.Locked) {
        state = State.Release;
        buyer.transfer(value);
    }

    function paySeller() external onlySeller inState(State.Release) {
        state = State.Inactive;
        seller.transfer( 3 * value);
    }
}
```